# Query conversion in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I change the given query:

```
  select 
   msi.attribute1 ref_no,
   msi.description,
   wdj.attribute10 order_id,
   wdj.net_quantity,
   '' Rec_date,
   '' Qty,
   '' packing_dated,
   trunc(sysdate) issue_date,
   hca.ACCOUNT_NUMBER||'-'||ooha.cust_po_number order_no,
   ooha.order_number sale_order_no,
    mci.attribute5 etching,
    we.wip_entity_name,
    weC.wip_entity_name "Relevant ASM job"    
  from  wip_discrete_jobs wdj,
    wip_entities we,
    oe_order_headers_all ooha,
    oe_order_lines_all oola,
    mtl_customer_items mci,
    mtl_system_items_b msi,
    fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv,
    hz_cust_accounts hca,
    wip_discrete_jobs wdjC,
    wip_entities weC
  where
   wdj.wip_entity_id = we.wip_entity_id
   and ooha.header_id=wdj.attribute10  
   and ooha.header_id=oola.header_id   
   and oola.line_id=wdj.attribute9
   and oola.ordered_item_id=mci.customer_item_id
   and wdj.primary_item_id=msi.inventory_item_id
   and msi.segment2 = ffvv.FLEX_VALUE
   and mci.customer_id=hca.cust_account_id
   AND wdjC.wip_entity_id = weC.wip_entity_id(+)
   AND wdjC.attribute1(+) = we.wip_entity_name 
   and wdj.organization_id = msi.organization_id     
   and ffvv.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = '1014875'
   and wdj.attribute10 = :order_id
```

to

```
 select 
   msi.attribute1 ref_no,
   msi.description,
   wdj.attribute10 order_id,
   wdj.net_quantity,
   '' Rec_date,
   '' Qty,
   '' packing_dated,
   trunc(sysdate) issue_date,
   hca.ACCOUNT_NUMBER||'-'||ooha.cust_po_number order_no,
   ooha.order_number sale_order_no,
    mci.attribute5 etching,
    we.wip_entity_name    
  from  wip_discrete_jobs wdj
   join wip_entities we    on wdj.wip_entity_id = we.wip_entity_id
   join oe_order_headers_all ooha      on ooha.header_id=wdj.attribute10  
   join oe_order_lines_all oola on ooha.header_id=oola.header_id   and oola.line_id=wdj.attribute9
   join mtl_customer_items mci on oola.ordered_item_id=mci.customer_item_id
   join mtl_system_items_b msi on wdj.primary_item_id=msi.inventory_item_id
   join fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv  on msi.segment2 = ffvv.FLEX_VALUE
   join hz_cust_accounts hca on mci.customer_id=hca.cust_account_id
   and wip_discrete_jobs wdjP inner join wip_entities weP on wdjP.WIP_ENTITY_ID=weP.WIP_ENTITY_ID       
   and wdj.organization_id = msi.organization_id     
   and ffvv.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = '1014875'
   and wdj.attribute10 = :order_id
```

Comment: You apparently already changed the query. So what is your question?

Comment: its giving error at and wip_discrete_jobs wdjP inner join wip_entities weP on wdjP.WIP_ENTITY_ID=weP.WIP_ENTITY_ID ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change old style joins to ANSI joins, but this part of your query is incorrect:

```
...
join hz_cust_accounts hca on mci.customer_id=hca.cust_account_id
                         and wip_discrete_jobs wdjP 
inner join wip_entities weP on wdjP.WIP_ENTITY_ID=weP.WIP_ENTITY_ID       
and wdj.organization_id = msi.organization_id ...
```

You didn't join table `wip_discrete_jobs` and you are trying to use it's column. Also this old syntax: 
`wdjC.wip_entity_id = weC.wip_entity_id(+)` should be changed to `left join`, not `inner join`. 
I wonder if `wip_discrete_jobs` is needed at all - there are no columns from this table in `select` clause?

Here is query, which should be equivalent to yours first, but please test it carefully 
because without your structures and data access I have no chance to verify it:

```
select msi.attribute1 ref_no, msi.description, wdj.attribute10 order_id, 
    wdj.net_quantity, '' Rec_date, '' Qty, '' packing_dated, 
    trunc(sysdate) issue_date, 
    hca.ACCOUNT_NUMBER||'-'||ooha.cust_po_number order_no, 
    ooha.order_number sale_order_no, mci.attribute5 etching, 
    we.wip_entity_name, weC.wip_entity_name "Relevant ASM job"    
  from wip_discrete_jobs      wdj
    join wip_entities         we   on wdj.wip_entity_id      = we.wip_entity_id
    join oe_order_headers_all ooha on ooha.header_id         = wdj.attribute10 
    join oe_order_lines_all   oola on ooha.header_id         = oola.header_id 
                                  and oola.line_id           = wdj.attribute9
    join mtl_customer_items   mci  on oola.ordered_item_id   = mci.customer_item_id
    join mtl_system_items_b   msi  on wdj.primary_item_id    = msi.inventory_item_id
                                  and wdj.organization_id    = msi.organization_id
    join fnd_flex_values_vl   ffvv on msi.segment2           = ffvv.FLEX_VALUE
                                  and ffvv.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = '1014875'
    join hz_cust_accounts     hca  on mci.customer_id        = hca.cust_account_id
    left join wip_discrete_jobs wdjC on wdjC.attribute1      = we.wip_entity_name
    left join wip_entities      weC  on wdjC.wip_entity_id   = weC.wip_entity_id
  where
    wdj.attribute10 = :order_id
```